# Text inside a button is not acting like part of the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Soon I'm releasing an album, so I decided to make a promo website for it. The website will be very simple: basically a list of buttons, each with the title of a song and a play button for playing a preview of that song. Also, when any button is clicked I want a popup to open. I'm pretty unexperienced, but I've managed to achieve all this. The only problem I have is that when I click on the title of any song in a button, which is inside a *P* tagg, the popup doesn't open. It only seems to work if I click on the *background* of the button, and I don't want that.

Also, something similar happens when de popup does open: I have programmed the popup to close if the user clicks outside the popup. And it works! But it also closes if I click on the text inside the popup.

I'm not sure why this is happening (maybe because of the way I used event listeners in my JS), but I would really appreciate if anyone could tell me how to make the text in the button act like part of the button, and how to avoid that clicking any text in the popup closes it.

I will leave a snippet here with all my code.

```js
var song1 = document.getElementById("SoloYoPreview");
var playbutton1 = document.getElementById("playbutton1");
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var toggle1 = 0;

var song2 = document.getElementById("LaNocheEnteraPreview");
var playbutton2 = document.getElementById("playbutton2");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var toggle2 = 0;

var song3 = document.getElementById("QueTalSiVamosPreview");
var playbutton3 = document.getElementById("playbutton3");
var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");
var toggle3 = 0;

var song4 = document.getElementById("EsUnRegaloPreview");
var playbutton4 = document.getElementById("playbutton4");
var button4 = document.getElementById("button4");
var toggle4 = 0;

var song5 = document.getElementById("NoMeQuieroMentirPreview");
var playbutton5 = document.getElementById("playbutton5");
var button5 = document.getElementById("button5");
var toggle5 = 0;

function ctrl_song(number, command = "") {
    var thissong = window["song"+number];
    var thisplaybutton = window["playbutton"+number];
    var thisbutton = window["button"+number];
    var thistoggle = window["toggle"+number];

    if (command == "stop") {
        window["toggle"+number] = 2;
        thisbutton.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
        thisplaybutton.src = "../../Icons/replay_circle_filled_black_48dp.svg";
        /*
        console.log("stopping");
        */

    } else if (command == "pause" || thistoggle == 1 ) {
        window["toggle"+number] = 0;
        thisbutton.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
        thissong.pause();
        thisplaybutton.src = "../../Icons/play_circle_filled_black_48dp.svg";
        /*
        console.log("pausing");
       */
        
    } else if (command == "restart" || thistoggle == 2) {
        window["toggle"+number] = 1;

        thisbutton.style.animationPlayState = "running";
        thissong.currentTime = 0;
        thissong.play();
        thisplaybutton.src = "../../Icons/pause_circle_filled_black_48dp.svg";
        /*
        console.log("restarting");
        */

    } else if (command == "play" || thistoggle == 0) {
        
        for (var i = 1;; i++) {
            try {
                window["toggle"+i] = 0;
                var fbutton = window["button"+i];
                fbutton.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
                var fsong = window["song"+i];
                fsong.pause();
                var fplaybutton = window["playbutton"+i];
                fplaybutton.src = "../../Icons/play_circle_filled_black_48dp.svg";
            } catch (e) {
                break;
            }
            
        }

        window["toggle"+number] = 1;

        thisbutton.style.animationPlayState = "running";
        thissong.play();
        thisplaybutton.src = "../../Icons/pause_circle_filled_black_48dp.svg";
        /*
        console.log("playing");
        */

    }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var sindex = e.target.dataset.sindex;
    ctrl_song(sindex);
});
document.addEventListener("animationiteration", function(e) {
    var sindexb = e.target.dataset.sindexb;
    ctrl_song(sindexb, "stop");
});









var popup = document.getElementById("popupid");
var popupshadow = document.getElementById("popupshadow");

function togglePopup(songtitle = "") {
    document.querySelector("#popuptitle").innerHTML = songtitle;
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
    popupshadow.classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    
    if (popup.className == "popup show" && event.target !== popup && event.target.className !== "songbuttons") {
        togglePopup();
    }    
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
  
  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1; 
}
   
  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888; 
}
  
  /* Handle on hover */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
#blurredbanner {
    width: auto;
    background-image: url("InflamaArtworkBlur.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
#albumcover {
    width: 350px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
p {
    margin-block-start: 0.67em;
    color: #111111;
}
h1 {
    margin-block-start: 0.67em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 15px;

    color: #111111;
}
#title {
    text-align: center;
}
#links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
button {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

    border: 1px solid #111111;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #111111;
    border-radius: 50px;

    font-size: 0.67em;

    margin-block-start: 45px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 50%;

    transition: 0.4s;

    background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(200,200,200,0.75), rgba(174,174,174,0.75) );
    -webkit-animation: progressbar 30s linear;
    animation: progressbar 30s linear infinite;
}
button:hover {
    transform: translate(0px, -8px);
}
@keyframes progressbar {
    0% {
        background-size: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        background-size: 100%;
    }
}
#button1 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
#button2 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
#button3 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
#button4 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
#button5 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.songtitle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    margin-block-start: 0px;
}
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    visibility: hidden;
    
    top: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    background-color: #ffffffaf;
    border-radius: 10px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);

    width: 25%;
    height: 50%;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    transition: 0.4s;
}
.popup h1 {
}
.popup.show {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 50%;
    width: 75%;
}
.popupshadow {
    background-color: #1111118f;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.6s;
}
.popupshadow.show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Inflama by Dherrera</TITLE>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="genericpromo.css">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV class="popupshadow" id="popupshadow"></DIV>

    <DIV id="blurredbanner">
        <IMG id="albumcover" src="InflamaArtwork.jpg">
    </DIV>

    <DIV id="title">
        <H1>Inflama</H1>
        <P>by Dherrera</P>
    </DIV>
    
    <DIV class="popup" id="popupid">
        <H1 id="popuptitle"></H1>
        <P>by Dherrera</P>
    </DIV>
    
    <DIV id="links">
        <button class="songbuttons" id="button1" data-sindexb="1" onclick="togglePopup('Solo Yo')">
            <audio id="SoloYoPreview">
                <source src="audio/SoloYoPreview.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>

            <img id="playbutton1" data-sindex="1" src="../../Icons/play_circle_filled_black_48dp.svg" >
            <P class="songtitle">Solo Yo</P>
        </button>

        <button class="songbuttons" id="button2" data-sindexb="2" onclick="togglePopup('La Noche Entera')">
            <audio id="LaNocheEnteraPreview">
                <source src="audio/LaNocheEnteraPreview.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>

            <img id="playbutton2"  data-sindex="2" src="../../Icons/play_circle_filled_black_48dp.svg">
            <P class="songtitle">La Noche Entera</P>
        </button>

        <button class="songbuttons" id="button3" data-sindexb="3" onclick="togglePopup('Que Tal Si Vamos')">
            <audio id="QueTalSiVamosPreview">
                <source src="audio/QueTalSiVamosPreview.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>

            <img class="playbtns" id="playbutton3"  data-sindex="3" src="../../Icons/play_circle_filled_black_48dp.svg">
            <P class="songtitle">Que Tal Si Vamos</P>
        </button>

        <button class="songbuttons" id="button4" data-sindexb="4" onclick="togglePopup('Es Un Regalo')">
            <audio id="EsUnRegaloPreview">
                <source src="audio/EsUnRegaloPreview.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>

            <img id="playbutton4"  data-sindex="4" src="../../Icons/play_circle_filled_black_48dp.svg">
            <P class="songtitle">Es Un Regalo</P>
        </button>

        <button class="songbuttons" id="button5" data-sindexb="5" onclick="togglePopup('No Me Quiero Mentir')">
            <audio id="NoMeQuieroMentirPreview">
                <source src="audio/NoMeQuieroMentirPreview.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>

            <img id="playbutton5"  data-sindex="5" src="../../Icons/play_circle_filled_black_48dp.svg">
            <P class="songtitle">No Me Quiero Mentir</P>
        </button>
    </DIV>
    
<!--SCRIPT-->
<SCRIPT src="genericpromov2.js"></SCRIPT>

</BODY>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The 'P' elements have no `data-sindex`. The click handlers are (only) working here when the 'IMG' or 'BUTTON' are the target, such that `e.target` has an expected dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only problem I have is that when I click on the title of any song
> in a button, which is inside a `<p>` tag, the popup doesn't open

You need to add this style to your CSS:

```
.songtitle {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This means that if anyone clicks on the `<p>` inside the `<button>`, it will be the `<button>` underneath which registers the click, rather than the `<p>`.

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Same should be added for the `h1` and `p` inside the pop up, to make it not close when clicking on text inside it.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! How dumb of me, it was a pretty problem. But I really appreciate your patience with me!

Comment: No worries, @DiegoHernandezHerrera - we're all here to learn. `pointer-events` is a really useful CSS property but there are many web developers (often those who tend to focus more on front-end javascript frameworks) who have not come across it.